# SharePoint Search

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

I currently have a Homepage and then 4 site collections within that.  I have added a search bar for users to search for all documents.  When I do the search 0 results come up and I can't figure this out.  (scope in your query does not exist) Any solutions to this?

Thanks

Comment: Follow the steps here and see if you still have the issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/sharepointsearch/thread/dae4a148-14d6-41c1-bc7e-b186b1a1240a

Comment: Thanks guys,  Basically what is happening is I can search within the site collections,  But I am trying to get the Homepage to search the entire site.  Which is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter your search criteria and return nothing, are you searching the correct scope from the drop-down

Comment: There are 4 different ones, on the drop down box for the homepage I am using the one that says ALL.  (meaning all sites).  This is the only thing on this site that I have not set up so Maybe something was not set up correctly.